# No microphone detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

For some reason I can no longer see my mic in the sound app / config application. The selection box is empty.

Internal microphone. Lenovo X1 rev 9.

[image]

However this lists a device:

```
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603d1c8000 irq 188"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Why is the system not recognizing this microphone?

thanks

Nikolaj Hansen

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? The output you show tells me it sees the sound hardware but does not give a clue why the mic is not working. You also have not said how the mic is attached. 3.5, USB or some other method. Please add the details to the question.

Comment: Info added with regards to distro and mic  and laptop type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy intel drivers will probably never support this chipset fully.

Here is how I finally fixed this:

1. Replace pulseaudio with pipewire. Follow this howto. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux
2. Install the firmware-sof-signed package. Replaces the old intel drivers.

   $> sudo apt install firmware-sof-signed

Verify the outcome (pulseaudio replacement):

```
nikolaj@ThinkPad-X1:~$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 1295
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: nikolaj
Host Name: ThinkPad-X1
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.65)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Headphone_Set-00.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source
Cookie: 1c6a:6bef
```

Verify the outcome (intel drivers replacement):

```
nikolaj@ThinkPad-X1:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Set [C-Media USB Headphone Set], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: J380 [Jabra Link 380], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
nikolaj@ThinkPad-X1:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 6: DMIC (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 7: DMIC16kHz (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: H2300 [HP Webcam HD 2300], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: J380 [Jabra Link 380], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
nikolaj@ThinkPad-X1:~$
```

I now have fully working microphones (plural since this laptop have several). The output devices work as they used to earlier.

Comment: Can you provide instructions for step 2 of this answer?