# No microphones detected Ubuntu 22.04.03 Lenovo Yoga

Tags: 22.04, hardware, microphone

I used to have microphones that would work with Bluetooth on an older ubuntu version. Now, on Jammy 22.04.03, I have audio, but no mic, regardless of how I connect the headset. I also have no mic recognized without a headset.

My system neither recognizes the internal mic, nor the usb headset mic. It *does* recognize the speakers (Momentum 3 by Sennheiser)

I have followed the instructions here: [No microphone detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437262/no-microphone-detected)

but have not been successful (i.e. still no mic appearing in sound settings).

I have also attempted a fix by installing `alsa-tools-gui` and overriding some items, and have not had any luck. I uninstalled it.

I'm seeing a lot of other people with similar issues, but I don't understand the answers, so I'm not sure if it's user error, or a system difference. What do I do next to troubleshoot/solve this issue?

Main goal: get my system to recognize it has microphones!